# How can I create a symfony twig filter?

Tags: symfony, twig

For instance my bundle namespace is `Facebook\Bundle\FacebookBundle\Extension`.

Using this how can I create a twig extension ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also create twig functions by using the getFunctions()

```
class FacebookExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'myFunction' => new Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'myFunction'),
        );
    }

    public function myFunction($arg1)
    {
        return $arg1;
    }
```

Use your function like this:

```
{{ myFunction('my_param') }}
```

Answer (score 35):

It's all here: [How to write a custom Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).

**1. Create the Extension:**

```
// src/Facebook/Bundle/Twig/FacebookExtension.php
namespace Facebook\Bundle\Twig;

use Twig_Extension;
use Twig_Filter_Method;

class FacebookExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'myfilter' => new Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'myFilter'),
        );
    }

    public function myFilter($arg1, $arg2='')
    {
        return sprintf('something %s %s', $arg1, $arg2);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'facebook_extension';
    }
}
```

**2. Register an Extension as a Service**

```
# src/Facebook/Bundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    facebook.twig.facebook_extension:
        class: Facebook\Bundle\Twig\AcmeExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

**3. Use it**

```
{{ 'blah'|myfilter('somearg') }}
```

Answer (score 15):

The Twig_Filter_Method class is **DEPRECATED** since Symfony 2.1

Please use the **Twig_SimpleFilter** class instead as showed in the following example:

*\src\Acme\Bundle\CoreBundle\Twig\DatetimeExtension.php*

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\CoreBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class DatetimeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'dateFormat' => new \Twig_SimpleFilter('dateFormat', array($this, 'dateFormat')),
            'datetimeFormat' => new \Twig_SimpleFilter('datetimeFormat', array($this, 'datetimeFormat'))
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $date
     * @return string
     */
    public function dateFormat($date)
    {
        $format = $this->container->getParameter('acme_core.date_format');
        return $this->format($date, $format);
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $date
     * @return string
     */
    public function datetimeFormat($date)
    {
        $format = $this->container->getParameter('acme_core.datetime_format');
        return $this->format($date, $format);
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $date
     * @param string $format
     * @throws \Twig_Error
     * @return string
     */
    private function format($date, $format)
    {
        if (is_int($date) || (is_string($date) && preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/iu', $date))) {
            return date($format, intval($date, 10));
        } else if (is_string($date) && !preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $date)) {
            return date($format, strtotime($date));
        } else if ($date instanceof \DateTime) {
            return $date->format($format);
        } else {
            throw new \Twig_Error('Date or datetime parameter not valid');
        }
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'datetime_extension';
    }
}
```

*\src\Acme\Bundle\CoreBundle\Resources\config\services.yml*

```
services:
    acme_core.twig.datetime_extension:
        class: Acme\Bundle\CoreBundle\Twig\DatetimeExtension
        arguments: [@service_container]
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Usage example:

```
{{ value|datetimeFormat }}
```

Symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Twig documentation: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#id3

Answer (score 2):

None of the given answers worked for Symfony 3.4 and above.

#### For Symfony 3.4, 4.x

```
// src/TwigExtension/customFilters.php 

namespace App\TwigExtension; 
use Twig\TwigFilter; 

class customFilters extends \Twig_Extension { 

    public function getFilters() { 
        return array( 
            new TwigFilter('base64_encode', array($this, 'base64_en'))
        );
    }

    public function base64_en($input) {
       return base64_encode($input);
    }
}
```

And then in your twig template you can do

```
{{ 'hello world' | base64_encode }}
```

Thats it. For detailed explanation, you could check out the reference.

**Reference**: **[DigitalFortress](https://digitalfortress.tech/php/create-custom-twig-filter-under-2-min/)**

Comment: I think this answer may be old, as for building custom Twig extension with `Symfony` 4.x and `Twig` 2.x See next two links: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html and https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-doctrine/twig-extension

Comment: Have you tested the code? It works exactly as its supposed to with `Symfony 3.4, 4.x` and `Twig 2.x` :)

Comment: First I told may be old not is not work, after checking I figure your code will work correctly But preferred  to change `extends \Twig_Extension ` To `extends Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension`, you can check AbstractExtension class will see setting `class_alias('Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension', 'Twig_Extension');` So your code work