# Creating Twig custom function - star rating

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.4

I want to create simple star rating function.

I want to to write in Twig template `{{ star (9) }}` and it should show image (or images) and text rating (9/10).

To pass variables to Twig I use in my controller:

```
$this->get('twig')->addGlobal('current_url',  $this->currentUrl);
```

and it works fine.

So in the same controller I use code:

```
    $function = new \Twig_SimpleFunction('star', function () {
        echo "test";
    });

    $this->get('twig')->addFunction($function);
```

and in Twig template I use:

```
{{ star }}
```

to display it. But it doesn't work at all (no error but also no result).

**Question**: How should it be written to make it work? And also - is it possible this function  this way that I assign some variables to Twig and simple include another Twig file in which stars will be created in loop?

I'm Symfony beginner. I saw [How can I create a symfony twig filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907137/how-can-i-create-a-symfony-twig-filter) but for me it's to complex at the moment - if possible I don't want to create new services / classes and so on to create simple function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a function, so it should be

```
{{ star() }}
```

Comment: Shame on me. It was so simple. Thanks!