# Convert StudlyCase and snake_case substrings to "spaced words" while preserving acronyms within twig expressions

Tags: php, symfony, replace, twig, reformatting

**Symfony twig**

How to add space following capital letters only when it is following small letters.

```
{{ 'IWantHTML'|humanize }} //displays 'I want h t m l'. // it should be 'I want HTML'.
```

The other thing is it makes everything small letters following the first letter.
e.x.

```
{{ 'IWantHTML'|humanize }} // should be 'I Want HTML'.
{{ 'i_want_html'|humanize}} // should be 'I want html'.
{{ 'CustomerPickSale2'|humanize}} // should be 'Customer Pick Sale2'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Below custom twig filter works!!**

```
new Twig_SimpleFilter('readable', array($this, 'readableFormat'))

 /**
 * @param $string
 * @return mixed
 */
public function readableFormat($string)
{
    $match_filter = array(
        '/(?<!\ )[A-Z][a-z]+/',
        '/(?<!\ )[A-Z][A-Z]+/',
    );

    $Words = preg_replace($match_filter, ' $0', trim($string));
    return str_replace('_', ' ', $Words);
}

{{ 'IWantHTML'|readable }} // I Want HTML
{{ 'i_want_html'|readable|ucfirst }} // I want html
{{ 'CustomerPickSale2'|readable|ucfirst }} // Customer Pick Sale2
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without using a match in the replacement.

- Match any underscore, or
- Match a lowercase letter, forget that letter with `\K`, lookahead for an uppercase letter, or
- Match an uppercase letter, forget that letter with `\K`, lookahead for an uppercase letter followed by a lowercase letter

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZJJvu))

```
$tests = [
    "{{ 'IWantHTML'|humanize }}", // should be 'I Want HTML'.
    "{{ 'i_want_html'|humanize}}", // should be 'I want html'.
    "{{ 'CustomerPickSale2'|humanize}}", // should be 'Customer Pick Sale2'
];

print_r(
    preg_replace('/_|[a-z]\K(?=[A-Z])|[A-Z]\K(?=[A-Z][a-z])/', ' ', $tests)
);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {{ 'I Want HTML'|humanize }}
    [1] => {{ 'i want html'|humanize}}
    [2] => {{ 'Customer Pick Sale2'|humanize}}
)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the snippet of humanize filter :

```
function humanize($str) {
    $str = trim(strtolower($str));
    $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\s+]/', '', $str);
    $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str);
    $str = explode(' ', $str);
    $str = array_map('ucwords', $str);
    return implode(' ', $str);
}
```

and you can see it does not do what you want.So you have to implement your own filter How to [Write Twig Extentions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) and how to create [Custom Twig Fitler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907137/how-can-i-create-a-symfony-twig-filter)

Comment: That doesn't look right. If that's the code for humanize it wouldn't do what it's doing right now.

I know how to write twig extension, I just need to know how to accomplish this.

Comment: @Archi, want to do something with humanize which is humanize not for that. the only solution for you need is custom extension or custom  pre preprocess you data in you're controller

Comment: I was looking for code on a custom filter.
The code you provided above is not even the code for humanize filter. I am not sure from where did you get that.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you this [Twig Extensions](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/templating/twig_extension.html)